# windows installation of R package

Tags: r

I'm running ubuntu, 64bit. I have this minimal test package
that i made to learn how to do these things (I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf&ei=IOvrUOe3G4rL0AWSjoGADA&usg=AFQjCNHmlajNmMov0zsiVa4dw9iyhupiDQ&sig2=CUYtDZA7v60R5PL9JmikOQ&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.d2k&cad=rja), except i also have some c code in the package). When i run

```
R CMD check MySmallPackage
```

on it, it works fine (see below). Then, 
I run

```
R CMD build MySmallPackage
```

and it works too (see below). So now, i send 
the resulting .tar.gz to a friend running win7 64 bit 
(and 64 bit R), and he gets this error message:

```
*** arch - i386
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'MySmallPackage'
* removing 'C:/Users/ES/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/MySmallPackage'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/x64/R CMD INSTALL -l "C:/Users/ES/Documents/R/win-library/2.15"   "C:/Users/ES/Downloads/MySmallPackage_0.1.1(1).tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/ES/Downloads/MySmallPackage_0.1.1(1).tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

It's very puzzling. Can anybody point me to what might be causing this problem (i have not used windows in many years but the package installs fine on linux). The error message is a bit cryptic to me.

```
$ R CMD check MySmallPackage
* using log directory ‘~/MySmallPackage.Rcheck’
* using R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
* using platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* checking for file ‘MySmallPackage/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package ‘MySmallPackage’ version ‘0.1.1’
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking whether package ‘MySmallPackage’ can be installed ... OK
* checking installed package size ... OK
* checking package directory ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking top-level files ... OK
* checking for left-over files ... OK
* checking index information ... OK
* checking package subdirectories ... OK
* checking R files for non-ASCII characters ... OK
* checking R files for syntax errors ... OK
* checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
* checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
* checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
* checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
* checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
* checking loading without being on the library search path ... OK
* checking for unstated dependencies in R code ... OK
* checking S3 generic/method consistency ... OK
* checking replacement functions ... OK
* checking foreign function calls ... OK
* checking R code for possible problems ... OK
* checking Rd files ... OK
* checking Rd metadata ... OK
* checking Rd cross-references ... OK
* checking for missing documentation entries ... OK
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... OK
* checking Rd \usage sections ... OK
* checking Rd contents ... OK
* checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
* checking line endings in C/C++/Fortran sources/headers ... OK
* checking line endings in Makefiles ... OK
* checking for portable compilation flags in Makevars ... OK
* checking for portable use of $(BLAS_LIBS) and $(LAPACK_LIBS) ... OK
* checking compiled code ... OK
* checking examples ... OK
* checking PDF version of manual ... OK


$R CMD build MySmallPackage
* checking for file ‘MySmallPackage/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘MySmallPackage’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building ‘MySmallPackage_0.1.1.tar.gz’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to build a different package for Linux, Mac and Windows machines.

There a (at least) four possibilities:

1. Host your package on [r-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/). Each night r-forge will build a linux, windows and mac version of the package.
2. Use the online windows [package builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org/) maintained by Uwe Ligges.
3. Send you friend the source code and get him to build the package on a Windows machince. When I googled "building r packages windows", I got a few useful hits.
4. Host your package on [github](https://github.com/) and then install the package using the [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) package.

Comment: thanks. '2.' worked and produced a usable .zip file. But it's horribly slow! I think this warrants a new question.

Comment: But 4) does not help with building, you still need Rtools.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel True, but provided you have Rtools installed, it is should be OK (speaking as a non-Windows user).

Comment: Huh? The point (and difficulty for some Windows folks) is getting Rtools installed and understood---your points 1) to 3) address that. But which remote storage you use is *entirely orthogonal*. Sorry, but neither github nor devtools cure the sick and feed the hungry. Which is why your point 4) is amusing at best.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I was thinking that the local computer administrator would install devtools and Rtools since these are "proper" R packages.    However, the local computer administrator wouldn't have time to mess about installing bespoke packages.

Comment: Look, if the local admin could install Rtools, there would be no question by the OP about how to build on Windows.  Your point 4 is fluff.  The other three are very good and relevant, and win-builder in particular is not as well know as it should be.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Around here (and at many other Uni), the administrator is happy to install a package, but would be very annoyed if you asked them to constantly update a package. The `install_github` option would all me to *instantly* change a package that the other non-technical user could install immediately. I agree the other options are better (hence the ordering) and that this option is "fluffy", but it can still be useful. BTW, any more comments should be moved to chat ;)