# windows version of R package much slower than linux version

Tags: r

I'm running ubuntu, 64bit. I have this minimal test package that i made to learn how to do these things (I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf&ei=IOvrUOe3G4rL0AWSjoGADA&usg=AFQjCNHmlajNmMov0zsiVa4dw9iyhupiDQ&sig2=CUYtDZA7v60R5PL9JmikOQ&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.d2k&cad=rja), except i also have some c code in the package).

The package build/runs in linux so i set about making it run in windows too.

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14212267/189035) and used the online windows package builder maintained by Uwe Ligges to get a (working) zip version of my [package](http://win-builder.r-project.org/AYd113V9vPd4/).

Now, when i install that .zip package on windows (7-64) the small demo code runs slower than the linux version. As in 30 times slower. I doubt the difference is always so large. 
I'm wondering what i'm doing wrong and how i can fix this gap.

## EDIT:

this is the source code (it's a minimal working example):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <Eigen/SVD>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using Eigen::MatrixXf;
using Eigen::VectorXf;


float median(VectorXf& x) {
    int n=x.rows();
    int half=(n+1)/2;   
    half--;                 
    float med;
    nth_element(x.data(),x.data()+half,x.data()+x.size());  
    if((n%2)==1){
        med=x(half);
    } else {
        float tmp0=x(half);
        float tmp1=x.segment(half+1,half-1).minCoeff(); 
        med=0.5*(tmp0+tmp1);
    }
    return med;
}
VectorXf fx01(MatrixXf& x){
    int p=x.cols();
    int n=x.rows();
    VectorXf Recept(n);
    VectorXf Result(p);
    for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
        Recept=x.col(i);
        Result(i)=median(Recept);
    }
    return Result;
}
extern "C"{
    void mse(int* n,int* p,float* x,float* medsout){
        MatrixXf x_cen=Map<MatrixXf>(x,*n,*p);  
        VectorXf MedsOut=fx01(x_cen);
        Map<VectorXf>(medsout,*p)=MedsOut.array();
    }
}
```

## EDIT2:

Following cbeleites suggestion i ran the code multiple times. Doing this I found 
a strange thing: the function's timing are actually the same as linux except when 
i call `apply()` before calling my function --I was always comparing the timing 
of the colwise median my pack computes to the timing of doing `apply(X,2,median)`--

Ok, problem solved. For now. Still i'm curious now: why would a good old fashioned 
call to `apply()` (on a huge matrix X) wreck things so badly (system.time went from 
90sec to 3sec)?

Comment: Can you also link the source of your package?

Comment: You may RcppEigen helpful---it lets you use `.Call()` more easily than the `.C()` interface you use here.

Comment: How does it scale? Calling with new data of same size, with larger data? Can you exclude that Windows needs more time e.g. loading the Eigen library (would be a 1st time difference, vanishing on further calls)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility that comes to my mind where calculations on different machines can differ about is the BLAS (if there are linear algebra calculations in the example).

Do you have an optimized BLAS installed on Ubuntu (e.g. libopenblas) but not on Windows?

Comment: thanks; indeed, i have atlas on the linux machine but not on the windows. I'll try to set up atlas on windows and see what difference it makes. The code doesn't use matrix operations though, so i don't think it will make much difference (compared to the factor 30 anyway)

Comment: Good hunch, but note that one of the amazing things about Eigen is that it does *not* always use BLAS but rather implements a lot itself in highly optimized SSE/SSE2/... code.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: the answer was a shot in the blue - the code wasn't posted then.

Comment: Sure. And a good shot. I even nodded to myself think "yep, that's it" and upvoted. But it may not be the full story.